# Landing and checking in again at LHR

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, lhr, short-connections

Has anyone travelled via London, where they needed to collect luggage at London airport and re-check in? I have an onward journey ticket and have Canadian PR.

I was given 2 different tickets where the time between both flights is 3 hours. Can someone help me with the best possible steps to complete this within the time frame?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your country of citizenship? You will need to pass UK immigration for this, which may require a visa depending on your nationality.

Comment: Are you sure there are two different tickets and not just two boarding passes?

Comment: If you want detailed advice, you'll have to specify which flights (or at least the airlines and origins/destinations). Depending on the combination, you may even have to change terminals, or, at the opposite end of the range, you may be able to check your luggage through to your destination.